# Fatal Error while pushing code to git

Tags: git

When I am trying to push code, I am getting the following error. But I can able to do git pull.

```
git push origin master
Counting objects: 98, done.
error: unable to find 5ddf9d6bfd7103fdc3d76e651e09af363c3b2dd5
error: unable to find d304aad6361e8b76919f60eb6fc03df4716a2a8d
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (65/65), done.
fatal: unable to read d304aad6361e8b76919f60eb6fc03df4716a2a8d
remote: fatal: early EOF
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:test.git'
```

Comment: Well it seems like you are trying to push a screwed history to the remote. Did you do any history rewriting on your local machine? Like rebase, reset, etc?

Comment: Yes. i did git pull --rebase and reset.  How do i solve this?

Comment: So what you actually did is: You screwed up the history. I hope for you, you are working on your own on this project? The only possibility for you to push your code to remote would be a forced push. This in turn rewrites remote history and your teammates will screw up their history with the next pull.

Comment: what are the steps needed to do solve this problem ? After I push, is this affect any other in teammates.

Comment: It will affect other teammates. Well it is pretty hard to suggest you a solution because we don't really know what you exactly did.

Comment: @ckruczek I did following to resolve issue. 1. Clone a new repo 2. Copy commit changes from old repo(which has push erros) to new repo. 3. then committed and pushed new repo.

Comment: Thats a possible solution